# Tense of noticing/realizing things

Tags: grammaticality

When you explain to someone that you realized or noticed something at a certain point, should the realizing or noticing be past perfect or simple past or present perfect?

> I **emailed** you because I **had realized** that you **would** not be here tomorrow.

> I **emailed** you because I **realized** that you **were** not going to be here tomorrow.

> We **decided** not to go because we **had noticed** that the place we **had chosen** **would/will** not be nice.

> We **noticed** that you **have created** your own program." or "We **noticed** that you **created** your own program.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

> I emailed you because I just realized that you {**aren't going to** / **won't**} be here tomorrow.

For the second sentence:

> We decided not to go because we noticed that the place we'd chosen **isn't** very nice.

And for the third sentence:

> We noticed that **you've created** your own program.
>   or
>   We noticed that **you created** your own program.

These are all idiomatic American English and appropriate for emails and other informal communication.

Comment: So I shouldn't push the realizing/noticing things further back by using past perfect, right?

Comment: @jess: It's not necessary, except in the second sentence in my answer, which is in past perfect: _the place we had chosen_. But for noticing/realizing that the choice was a bad one, no, you don't need the past perfect in this context.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. For the second sentence, can I do what you did in the first sentence? "...the place we had chosen won't be very nice"?

Comment: And so for something like this, "I was wondering where it went," I should use "where it had went," right?

Comment: @jess: If it's generally not very nice, then use the simple  present because it's habitually "not very nice"; otherwise, it means "not very nice" is exceptional & a transient condition. "Where it had **gone**" is the correct form, but in this case, "where it was" is also fine. There is usually more than one "proper/standard/natural/correct" way of saying things: context is always important.